# Rails parse JSON response for jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, datatables

I have a small problem with the ajax function of jQuery DataTables and with the JSON response, I get in my Rails 6 application. I'm successfully accessing the route and getting back a JSON response.

What I want to achieve: I count the number of records with specific attributes for every day, so I get back an integer value. My problem is: How can I pass this value to jQuery DataTables to appear in the columns?

My controller action:

```
 def showDailyOrders
    render json: 
    { count1: OrderCard.where(day: Date.today).where(dish_type: 0).count }
  end
```

My jQuery code to initialize the DataTable and the AJAX request:

```
$("#todaysOrdersTable").DataTable({
            ajax: '/showDailyOrders',
            dataSrc: '',
            columns: [
                { title: 'Vollkost', data: 'count1' }
            ]
        });
```

The JSON response I get looks like this:

```
"{\"count1\":1}"
```

How do I pass the value (1 in this case) to the jQuery function? It's just telling me "Loading", but nothing happens. If I use another query like OrderCard.all as response and use the key (for example "id") as data in the function, it's displaying the value.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The easiest way is to use this gem: Ajax-DataTables-Rails gem here: https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails  which will help you compartamentalize all of your datatables.  Typically you'll make a datatables class for a table and feed the view.context to it like: format.json { render json: DailyOrderDatatable.new(params) }

Comment: Yeah, I know that there*s a gem but I rather go with the "normal" library. I just need to know how I get the value.

Comment: Follow this railscast then. Explains everything in full detail without gems: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables  Basically you'll make a class that handles returning the properly formatted json response which is really just an array that follows the structure of columns on your table.

Comment: That's why I ask how to get this JSON response as properly formatted one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSrc` option does not exist and thus will be negated. Instead use the [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option:

```js
$("#todaysOrdersTable").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/showDailyOrders',
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  columns: [
    { title: 'Vollkost', data: 'count1' }
  ]
});
```

After fixing the `dataSrc` option you still have the issue that the returned value is a single value instead of an array. When you return `OrderCard.all` you return a array of values, which is why it works.

This means we have to convert the single returned object `{"count1":1}` into an array that holds the object `[{"count1":1}]`. This can either be done on the client- or server-side. On the client-side it should look something like this:

```js
$("#todaysOrdersTable").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/showDailyOrders',
    dataSrc: obj => [obj], // transform into an array
  },
  columns: [
    { title: 'Vollkost', data: 'count1' }
  ]
});
```

Or if you rather change the server-side it should look something like this:

```rb
order_cards = OrderCard.where(day: Date.today).where(dish_type: 0)
# note that the object is now wrapped inside an array
render json: [{ count1: order_cards.count }]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could force the rendering as JSON as an array, with the server-side conversion and the right dataSrc method it works! You saved my day :D